# Obtener el dato seleccionado de un form-select en php ajax para insertar en base de datos

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Quisiera obtener el valor de lo tiene `select` para poder ingresarlo a la base de datos.

Me lo piden con ajax. Son dos archivos: uno donde esta el formulario y otro donde agrega a la base de datos.

Llevo dias intentandolo y no me logra salir correcto.  Recalco que si estoy conectado a la base de datos, no se como obtener la opcion que  ha elegido el usuario para su posterior almacenaje.

**Formulario**

```
<form id="frmajax1"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select class="form-select" name= "tipoinmueble" id= "tipoimnueble" aria-label="Default select example" required>
<label>Tipo de inmueble</label>
<option selected>Elige</option>
<option value="Casa">Casa</option>
<option value="Terreno">Terreno</option>
<option value="Predio">Predio</option>
</select>
<select class="form-select"  name= "condicioninmueble" id="condicioninmueble" aria-label="Default select example" required>
<label>Condicion</label>
<option selected>Elige</option>
<option value="Venta">Venta</option>
<option value="Renta">Renta</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="text-center mb-5">
<button type="submit" name="frmajax1" style="margin-left:5% ; width: 100px; height: 50px;" class="btn btn-primary " value="SAVE">
Registrar
</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#frmajax1").on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/js/agregarback.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(r) {
          //alert(r);
          if (r == 1) {
            alert("¡Realizado con éxito!");
            document.getElementById('frmajax1').setAttribute("class", "disabled");
          } else {
            alert(" ¡Ocurrió un error al guardar el inmueble!");
            document.getElementById('frmajax1').setAttribute("class", "disabled");
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
})();
```

**Backend** donde se realiza la inserción

```
<?php
require_once('config/functions.php');
$tipo = $_POST['tipoinmueble'];
$condicioninmueble = $_POST['condicioninmueble'];


//insert form data in the database

$statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO inmuebles (Tipo, Condicion) VALUES (:tipe, :cond )");

if( $statement->execute(array(
    ':tipe' => $tipo,
    ':cond' => $condicioninmueble,
) )){
    $sqlU = 1;//Insertado correctamentee
}else{
    $sqlU = 0;//Sucedió un error en la insercion
    die(print_r($statement->errorInfo(), true));
}
```

?>

Comment: No has pegado el ajax. Haz el [tour] y mírate [ask], asi como tambien [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte sin darnos trabajo extra, o bien tu pregunta será cerrada por falta de datos.

Comment: Perdone soy nuevo en esto tendre mas cuidado

Comment: A ver, tu formulario no parece que tenga nada que ver con los datos a insertar.  Pon el formulario correcto, ese que has puesto solo es para subir imagenes del inmueble.  No se como quieres capturar las variables $tipo, $domicilio, etc, si no las pides de algun modo.

Comment: bien deja lo corrijo

Comment: Prueba quitando la linea del `cache: false` pues eso solo sirve para peticiones GET. No creo que sea eso, pero empieza por ahi. Y yo probaria definir una variable antes del `$.ajax` así: `fd = new FormData(this);` y sustiuiria el `data: new FormData(this),`  por `data: fd,`.  Ya nos diras si asi funciona.